# Django email attaches attachments as text to the bottom of the email

Tags: django, email, mime

I'm using django to send an email, using django's built in `from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives`. It is supposed to be attaching a number of .eml files, and a couple of CSVs. The CSVs attach as expected, but the .eml files do two things: they attach, but they also appear, in full, in the body of the email. I assume that this is because they are .eml files, but is there a way to stop them from doing so?
For example, the email arrives looking like this:

```
Body of email
Full content of foo.eml
Full content of bar.eml
Attachments:
foo.eml, bar.eml, x.csv
```

I would like the full content of foo.eml and bar.eml not to appear in the actual body of the email. The attachment command is `msg.attach_file(attachment.name, attachment.path)`

Comment: Try a different email client? The client might be displaying it for you automatically.

Comment: I've tried airmail, on a mac, and the gmail webmail...